# Duvida de C++ laço do-while

Tags: c, c++, loop

Bom gente, eu to com a seguinte dúvida:

Toda vez que eu rodo esse programam o laço do-while não para no scanf do segundo laço no programa e acaba rodando duas vezes e exibindo a mensagem de erro. Eu gostaria de saber como concertar esse bug.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){

int a1, a2, media;
char op;

do{

    printf("Digite a primeira nota: ");
    scanf("%i", &a1);

    printf("\nDigite a segunda nota: ");
    scanf("%i", &a2);

    printf("\n\nMEDIA: %d", ((a1+a2)/2));

    do{
        printf("\n\nDigite 's' para rodar o programa denovo ou 'n' para encerrar: ");
        scanf("%c", &op);

        if ((op!='s') && (op!='n')){
            printf("Opcao invalida");
        }

    }while((op!='s') && (op!='n'));     
}while(op!='n');

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Como assim 'nao para' ? vc pode mostrar como sai no console?

Comment: eu respondi abaixo - mas vai um conselho off topic: se você quer aprender lógica de programação, sem ter que se preocupar com a lógica de baixo nível de stream de arquivos, alocação de memoria,e  ainda ter programas que possam fazer tarefas reais, tente uma linguagem de mais alto nível, como Python ou Ruby. Em C/C++, uma simples leitura da entrada do usuário pode, além dos problemas que você teve, acrescentar falhas perigosas de segurança - vide minha resposta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu aconselho você usar o `getchar()`. Para funcionar com o `scanf` você deve limpar o buffer com `flush(stdin)` porque o enter `\n` fica no `stdin`.

Comment: Ainda não conheço essas funções, não sou muito familiarizado com a sintaxe do c/c++, mas obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: antes de seu sacanf basta colocar 'flush(stdin);'. Quando você digita o valor da variável i e tecla enter o seu próximo scanf que nesse caso é o primeiro do segundo do-while lê o enter que está no buffer, por isso que você deve limpar com flush(stdin);

Comment: É comum o `flush()` não funcionar, então a solução deve ser o `getchar()`.

Comment: Mas o getchar não retira o '\n'  do stdin também - o programa vai até funcionar, mas sem um flush, vai exibir a mensagem de 'opção inválida' por conta do '\n'

Answer (score 1):

A leitura da entrada padrão pode ser um pouco chata as vezes - as funçoes scanf e printf foram escritas  há mais de 30 anos atrás, quando a capacidade dos terminais (e de interface para os programas em geral) eram bem aquem do são hoje.

A entrada padrão funciona como um arquivo de texto - que por questões de otmização, a não ser que vocẽ troque algumas configurações bem complicadas, sempre é lido linha por linha - por isso, mesmo usando `%c` no `scanf`, ou a função `getchar` como sugerido na outra resposta, o usuário vai ter que pressionar `<enter>` - e esse `<enter>` vai ser lido  - ou no próximo `scanf`, ou no próximo `getchar`.

O melhor é não tentar ler caractere por caractere - o usuário vai ter que apertar enter mesmo. Se você desejar criar uma interface que responda a atalhos de teclado, então é melhor usaruma biblitoeca de console, como ncurses - ela faz ajustes na configuração da stdin de forma que você possa ler tecla a tecla sem efeitos colaterais. Mas isso é um estágio além da familiarização com a linguagem que é o ponto do seu programa atual - e possivelmente, vale mais a pena aprender a usar uma biblioteca gráfica para interface do que o ncurses (gtk, qt, etc...)

Por fim, para o seu programa atual, use o scanf com "%s" - mas - lembre-se, *sempre* que  usar o scanf para ler uma string, é necessário pensar o que aconteceria se o usuário digitasse mais dados do que cabem na sua string para armazenar os dados. Simples: os dados a mais vazam par aoutras regiões da memória em uso pelo seu programa e isso causa o famoso "buffer overflow". Para mitigar isso, o "%s" deve ser usado com o número máximo de caracteres que o usuário deve digitar, entre "%" e o "s" - `scanf("%21s")` - aceita uma string de até 20 caractéres (e mais o \x00 final).

O seu programa pode ser feito assim:

```
char op[3]; //suficiente para conter a letra da opção, o \n e o \x00
...
scanf("%2s", op) // op já é um ponteiro - não precisa do &
...
while (op[0] != 's') && (op[0] != 'n') // verifica apenas o 1º caractere da string op
```